# How to wait for an NPM command to finish before proceeding to the following command?

Tags: node.js, shell, npm, wait

I created a shell script that intends to remove all node modules, reinstall them, build the code base, and start the server. Part of it looks like this:

```
# Install backend
rm -rf "./backend/node_modules/"
npm ci --no-fund --prefix "./backend"  # <-- (1)

# Build backend
npm --prefix "./backend" run build     # <-- (2)
```

However, what happens is that the `run build` command (1) executes before NPM has finished installing all packages (2).

How can I make sure that (1) has finished before (2) is executed?

Comment: It shouldn't be possible. In order for the commands to run in parallel, you need to apply special treatments (or commands that move into the background). In your case, I suggest that you follow the commands sequentially: `rm -rf "./backend/node_modules/" && npm ci --no-fund --prefix "./backend" && echo "finish install" && npm --prefix "./backend" run build && echo `DONE``

Comment: maybe it's just a short timing problem. Have you tried adding `sleep 1` between the two commands?

Comment: @bato3, sequential execution is indeed what I'm looking for. When I cut all my commands from the script and paste them sequentially separated by &&, it indeed seems to work. However, why doesn't this work when I have the same command in a `.sh` file? The only difference is a newline after the && character (to keep the script readable). Might this explain it?

Comment: @SoulKa same result as without `sleep 1`

Comment: Probably some magic with detecting how to run and parallelizing the execution. Maybe in NPM or maybe at the OS level. It has been assumed that if the order of execution of commands is to be adhered to, `&&` should be used.

Comment: So strange, because if I add the command as a single line in the `sh` file (so separated by &&, no newline) it works, but as multiline (separated by && and a newline) it doesn't. I'd really prefer the latter, since the "one line" version of the script is not at all readable.

Comment: oops... I forgot that the script set a shell variable that influenced the behavior of NPM (`export NODE_ENV=production`). This explains it all... Without the flag, this question wouldn't even have been necessary, everything already executes sequentially.